# Disable the position change of seekbar till an event finishes

Tags: android, seekbar, android-seekbar

I have a seekBar in my app. Based on the requirement, on changing the seekbar position by touching on it, the seekBar will wait for an event to be completed and based on the event response, the value on the seekbar will be changed later on.

the process will be like:

Change seekbar position--> wait for event to be completed---> get the event result---> seekBar position changed to the corresponding Value.

I have searched enough solutions but am unable to resolve. Even though if you are going to downvote, please give a solution before that. Thank you.

Comment: please post your code for us to be able to help you

Comment: @SecretCoder: Please read the description. Its a certain condition which I am unable to achieve. I myself haven't got the correct code for this case.

Comment: well its easier to explain if you have some codes already but i will explain what you will likely need to develop. First Seekbar has a callback function when you change it. this will call every time you change seekbar. You can add your code for the event(most likely call from web service). Every event has a callback also for start and finished state, there you will call the seekbar  to enable and disable state.

Comment: @SecretCoder: thank you. Issue resolved.:)